# Get array values which are not being compared

Tags: php, arrays

Currently, lets assume I have two arrays as follow:

```
  $values1= array(1, 2, 3);
  $values2= array(1, 3, 4);
```

If I compare both arrays in loop I would be able to differentiate which array elements of first array is not being compared. For example :

```
             $data=array();
            foreach($values1 as $value) {

                    if(! in_array($value, $values2 )) {
                        $data[]=$value;
                   }
            }
```

In this way i would be figure out that `2` is the value which is not in the `$value2 array` but at the same time i also wanted to know what are the other extra elements which are not being compared in `$valnues2 array` such as `4` in this case.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you don't mind using a function, but you could merge them both and compare them to the ones with their similar values to get the differences. Like this:

```
$values1 = array(1, 2, 3);
$values2 = array(1, 3, 4);
$others = array_diff(array_merge($values1, $values2), array_intersect($values1, $values2));
echo '<pre>';
print_r($others);
```

Should output something like:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [5] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_diff()` only checks for elements existing in arg 1 that don't exist in arg 2, one way to get around this is to check both ways and merge the results:

```
function array_diff_both($a, $b) {
    $d1 = array_diff($a, $b);
    $d2 = array_diff($b, $a);
    return array_merge($d1, $d2);
}

print_r(array_diff_both($values1, $values2));
```

Example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
)
```

---

Looking forward, it might be best to pass arrays in as an array so you could expand this function's use with the number of your arrays.